# protobuf-net v2 With Circular References

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

As far as I know protobuf-net starting from v2 supports references.

I'm currently trying to use it in a data structure where circular references may occur like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class WaypointDatabase
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public List<Waypoint> Waypoints { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
internal class Waypoint
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public string Ident { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public List<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
internal class Route
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public Waypoint PreviousWaypoint { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public Waypoint NextWaypoint { get; set; }
}
```

So the main object that is serialized with protobuf-net is an instance of `WaypointDatabase`. This object contains `Waypoints` with a list of `Routes` which direct to `Waypoints` again.

The reason I want to use this data stucture is that there are waypoints which are not included in/referenced by a route. Therefore I need this waypoint database to keep track of all waypoints whether they are within existent routes or not.

When I now try to serialize the instance of `WaypointDatabase` with protobuf-net, I get an StackOverflowException and I don't understand why, because I marked the `Waypoint` class as `AsReferenceDefault` and I thought this would make sure protobuf-net only stores the reference if it is used again (and this way should not follow the circular reference endlessly).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any tip on that

Andreas

P. S.: I'm using version 2.0.0.668 of protobuf-net in case that's related to a specific version.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?